# df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\DJ_PRATIK28\Downloads\titanic.xlsx")

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xlsx

i want to load the csv file in dataframes i'll try many option but is not working

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DJ_PRATIK28\Downloads\titanic.xlsx","r", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: you can't use `pd.read_csv` to read in an `.xlsx` file – try `pd.read_excel` instead.  i'd also recommend that you be more descriptive in your question or people will vote to close it. what isn't working? i imagine you must be getting an error message – you should include that in your question. i'd recommend you read through stackoverflow's guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.read_excel`:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\DJ_PRATIK28\Downloads\titanic.xlsx")
```